# Tensorflow feed multiple parameters through input_fn pipeline

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network, tensorflow-estimator

I am writing a high-level tensorflow application exactly the same way [this minst estimator](https://github.com/peterroelants/tf_estimator_example/blob/master/src/mnist_estimator.py) is build except that I am building a simple RNN that predicts sequences. I am new to tensorflow so I am trying to get head around an issue that might be actually simple for people who have worked in tensorflow high level api before.

Here is a snippet of my code to give an idea:

```
def main(argv=None):
    """Run the training experiment."""
    ....
    # Setup the Estimator
    model_estimator = build_estimator(config, params)
    # Setup and start training and validation
    train_spec = tf.estimator.TrainSpec(
        input_fn=lambda: get_train_inputs(128),
        max_steps=2000)
    ...
    tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(model_estimator, train_spec, eval_spec)

def build_estimator(config, params):
    return tf.estimator.Estimator(
        model_fn=model_fn,
        config=config,
        params=params,
    )

def model_fn(features, mode, params):
    #Input data
    _inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[batch_size, times_steps])
    _labels = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[batch_size, num_classes])
    # Sequence lengths for dynamic allocation
    _seqlens = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[batch_size])
    ...
    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(
        mode=mode,
        predictions=predictions,
        loss=loss,
        train_op=train_op,
        eval_metric_ops=eval_metric_ops
    )
```

Here is my input pipleine function:

```
# Get train inputs function
def get_train_inputs(batch_size):
    def train_inputs(batch_size):
            # Build dataset iterator
            x_batch, y_batch, seqlen_batch = sequence_generator.get_sentence_batch(
                batch_size, sequence_generator.train_x, sequence_generator.train_y, sequence_generator.train_seqlens)
            features={'_inputs': x_batch, '_labels': y_batch, '_seqlens': seqlen_batch}
            return features
    return train_inputs(batch_size)
```

Due to the size of my code, I have only pasted relevant pieces of code here. 
The problem here is that during:

```
train_spec = tf.estimator.TrainSpec(
    input_fn=lambda: get_train_inputs(128),
    max_steps=2000)
```

`get_train_inputs(128)` feeds the `features` dictionary into _inputs placeholder of the `model_fn` so the `_labels` and `_seqlens` remain blank and throw out error during execution that no values specified for these  place holders. The `model_fn` only accepts two feature parameters : `features` and `labels`. How do I feed all the three parameters `_inputs`, `_labels` and `_seqlens` into the model?

Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

*NOTE*: The reason for inputing a third parameter `_seqlens` is because I am using `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn` in my `model_fn` which requires sequence lengths where as labels are being used in `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` in my softmax function.

Answer (score 1):

You're not supposed to use placeholders at all with `tf.Estimator`. You should look into the `tf.data` API ([see here](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/datasets)). Your input function should return the `get_next` op of a one shot iterator. Apologies if you are already doing this, but it is not clear from your code what exactly your input function is returning.
Assuming you set this up to return a dict as in your example, you will then be able to simply use `_inputs = features["_inputs"]` etc. in your model function.

Answer (score 0):

- In addition to @xdurch0 answer, use FeatureColumns
  [tf.feature_column](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/feature_column) to describe the features of the dataset that are passed as inputs into the Estimator `model_fn` for training and evaluation.
- Within the `model_fn`, use the method
  [tf.feature_column.input_layer()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/feature_column/input_layer)` to return a dense Tensor as an
  input layer based on a specified FeatureColumn.

  You can see examples of working with FeatureColumns [here](https://developers.googleblog.com/2017/11/introducing-tensorflow-feature-columns.html).